# Mesa3D install can't find libdrm

Tags: configuration, mesa

I'm currently trying to manually install Mesa (version 10.2.3) on a server for which I do not have root access.  After downloading the source, I run the configure file with `.\configure --prefix=$HOME/.../PATH/TO/MESA`.  I get the following readout:

```
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for ar... ar
checking the archiver (ar) interface... ar
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... (cached) yes
checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) gcc3
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for gmake... gmake
checking for python2... python2
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 3458764513820540925
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... no
checking if : is a manifest tool... no
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... no
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... no
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for bison... bison -y
checking if bison is the parser generator... yes
checking for flex... flex
checking lex output file root... lex.yy
checking lex library... -lfl
checking whether yytext is a pointer... yes
checking if flex is the lexer generator... yes
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for indent... cat
checking if compiling with clang... no
checking whether gcc version is sufficient... yes
checking for __builtin_bswap32... yes
checking for __builtin_bswap64... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking whether gcc supports -Werror=missing-prototypes... yes
checking whether gcc supports -fvisibility=hidden... yes
checking whether g++ supports -fvisibility=hidden... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -msse4.1... yes
checking whether ld supports --gc-sections... yes
checking whether to enable assembly... yes, x86_64
checking for dlopen... no
checking for dlopen in -ldl... yes
checking for dladdr... yes
checking for clock_gettime... no
checking for clock_gettime in -lrt... yes
checking for posix_memalign... yes
checking for the pthreads library -lpthreads... no
checking whether pthreads work without any flags... no
checking whether pthreads work with -Kthread... no
checking whether pthreads work with -kthread... no
checking for the pthreads library -llthread... no
checking whether pthreads work with -pthread... yes
checking for joinable pthread attribute... PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE
checking if more special flags are required for pthreads... no
checking for PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT... no
checking for LIBDRM... no
checking for LIBUDEV... no
checking for GLPROTO... yes
configure: error: Direct rendering requires libdrm >= 2.4.38
```

However, when I use `locate libdrm`, I get the following:

```
/install/rocks-dist/x86_64/RedHat/RPMS/libdrm-2.4.45-2.el6.x86_64.rpm
/usr/lib64/libdrm.so.2
/usr/lib64/libdrm.so.2.4.0
/usr/lib64/libdrm_intel.so.1
/usr/lib64/libdrm_intel.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib64/libdrm_nouveau.so.1
/usr/lib64/libdrm_nouveau.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib64/libdrm_nouveau2.so.2
/usr/lib64/libdrm_nouveau2.so.2.0.0
/usr/lib64/libdrm_radeon.so.1
/usr/lib64/libdrm_radeon.so.1.0.1
/usr/share/doc/libdrm-2.4.45
/usr/share/doc/libdrm-2.4.45/README
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/l/093e922ee5fe0bcee6c2de28500239d06027be18-libdrm-2.4.45-2.el6-x86_64
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/l/093e922ee5fe0bcee6c2de28500239d06027be18-libdrm-2.4.45-2.el6-x86_64/checksum_data
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/l/093e922ee5fe0bcee6c2de28500239d06027be18-libdrm-2.4.45-2.el6-x86_64/checksum_type
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/l/093e922ee5fe0bcee6c2de28500239d06027be18-libdrm-2.4.45-2.el6-x86_64/from_repo
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/l/093e922ee5fe0bcee6c2de28500239d06027be18-libdrm-2.4.45-2.el6-x86_64/from_repo_revision
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/l/093e922ee5fe0bcee6c2de28500239d06027be18-libdrm-2.4.45-2.el6-x86_64/from_repo_timestamp
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/l/093e922ee5fe0bcee6c2de28500239d06027be18-libdrm-2.4.45-2.el6-x86_64/installed_by
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/l/093e922ee5fe0bcee6c2de28500239d06027be18-libdrm-2.4.45-2.el6-x86_64/reason
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/l/093e922ee5fe0bcee6c2de28500239d06027be18-libdrm-2.4.45-2.el6-x86_64/releasever
```

This seems to indicate to me that libdrm version 2.4.45 is already installed on the system, so why am I still getting an error? I tried running the configure file again with the default prefix and the same error occurs.

UPDATE: The problem is moot for me now as the server admin added OpenGL to the system.  Feel free to write an answer, though, as it might help someone having similar issues.

Answer (score 6):

Installing the libdrm-dev package solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

just set the following variables:

```
export LIBDRM_CFLAGS="-I${LIBDRM_ROOT} -I${LIBDRM_ROOT}/libdrm"
export LIBDRM_LIBS="-L${LIBDRM_ROOT}/lib -ldrm"
```

as `LIBDRM_ROOT` have the path for the installed LIBDRM package.